# Access token ou Sessions em APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Estou desenvolvendo um api e estou com uma dúvida sobre como manipular o usuário logado. A api e administração do usuário logado (adicionar coisas, editar perfil, fotos, etc.) está desenvolvida em Rails em um único projeto.

Como tenho uma parte muito interativa nesse projeto, e estou utilizando o React para consumir a api. Essa parte é um projeto a parte que roda em um subdomínio. Hoje estou utilizando sessões para identificar o estado do usuário. Algum problema em continuar assim? Segurança? Performance? Cache?

Ex: O usuário loga em www.dominio.com (Rails+API+Adm) e quando vai para projeto.dominio.com (Projeto separado) ele permanece logado, fazendo requisições para GET www.dominio.com/api/v1/amigos.json com resultados específicos para esse usuário. Na api eu identifico esse usuário via sessão e não por query sting e nenhum tipo de parâmetro.

Outra dúvida: Quando o usuário logar, eu poderia criar um access_token e armazenar em sessão, para que ele navegue e faça consultas com esse access_token na api? Eliminado assim que minha api tenha que consultar a sessão e consulta pelo access_token.

Em um outro projeto que estou desenvolvendo em paralelo, a api está com access_tokens, entretando só tem a api, não tenha nada além dos serviços em rest.

Comment: Gostaria de estar em casa para responder sua pergunta. Lá pelas 21h, eu respondo. Por enquanto, me diga quantos usuários simultâneos sua aplicação pretende suportar. Até mais.

Comment: Não tenho um número definido, mas seriam vários.. Eu vi que com o access token tenho mais flexibilidade para escalar, certo?

Answer (score 1):

## JSON Web Tokens VS Sessions

Se estivermos falando sobre **escalabilidade**, não é possível usar somente Sessions porque o uso de memória ou I/O que você vai precisar é gigantesco. Usando somente JWT, tanto faz ter 10, 100 ou 100 milhões de usuários, mas nem tudo é somente doce.

**O modelo híbrido** é, normalmente, o melhor. Você pode persistir sessions para que o estado do seu usuário seja persistido entre vários dispositivos diferentes. Enquanto isso, o uso do JWT pode te auxiliar na redução do tráfego de rede e operações de I/O. Os JWT podem ser usados também para te dar uma aplicação de [Login Único](http://adamalbrecht.com/2015/07/20/authentication-using-json-web-tokens-using-rails-and-react/), onde as credenciais do usuário só serão utilizadas no primeiro login e, depois, você utilizará tokens de autorização para renovar seus tokens normais.

Para sua aplicação ter o **estado mantido**, basta assinar seu JWT com alguma informação relevante ao estado do usuário. Lembre-se que o JWT pode guardar qualquer informação que você quiser no lado do cliente, com o cliente sem conseguir ler aquilo. Você pode adicionar a rota atual, o caminho que ele percorreu e persistir no database depois, pode guardar o `nomeDeUsuario` ou algum token aleatório usado para identificar a sessão.

Sobre **tráfego de rede**, conforme você vai adicionando informações ao JWT, ele vai crescendo e, com isso, cresce também o tráfego de dados. É necessário perceber que cada estratégia possui um ponto negativo, sendo o uso do **processador** para decodificar os tokens o negativo dos JWT. Enquanto isso, o lado negativo das sessions é o uso de **I/O e RAM**.

Algo importante a se notar é que o **design de sua aplicação** deverá perceber quando é necessário fazer uso de I/O, sessions in-memory ou JWT.

> Dois exemplos de aplicações minhas que posso te dar:

- 1) Uma aplicação empresarial para 50~100 pessoas com pouco acesso.

Nessa aplicação, não me importei com muita coisa. As 50~100 seções estavam sempre na RAM para garantir o estado dos usuários. Uma queda de energia e 'xablau'. Enquanto isso, o login dos usuários era feito somente uma vez e, após isso, o servidor mandava um JWT somente com o `username` do usuário, que era utilizado para identificá-lo e salvo nos cookies. O servidor confiava no JWT criptografado e tomava o username como verdadeiro. Enquanto isso, a cada login o JWT era renovado por mais uma semana e, caso estivesse vencido, o servidor solicitava as credenciais.

- 2) Uma aplicação de aprendizado, um jogo escalável.

Nessa aplicação, não haviam sessões. O usuário simplesmente cria a conta, recebe seu JWT, que é armazenado no [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) e fica logado para sempre. Sempre que ele vai para a aplicação, sua conta é identificada e um I/O é feito para lhe criar um personagem para jogar com base nas partidas anteriores. Sempre que o jogador morre, é feito outro I/O para salvar algumas informações sobre a partida e o personagem morto.

> Resumo rápido

**Tokens**

- Padronizado pela [RFC 7519](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7519).
- Bastante compatível com dispositivos móveis.
- Consome mais CPU, mas menos RAM
- Inseguro.
- Nasceu para ser pequeno e manter logado com único login.
- Armazenado no cliente, processado no servidor.

**Sessions**

- Apesar de não ser padronizado, é largamente utilizado.
- Workarounds para lidar com mobile.
- Consome mais RAM e I/O, mas menos CPU.
- Inseguro.
- Nasceu para 'manter usuário logado'.
- Armazenado no servidor.

Tudo é inseguro, só deixei como um lembrete. ;)